# Order of growth in uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-function, statistical-inference

Consider an i.i.d. sample $\{X_1, \ldots , X_n\}$ from the uniform distribution on 
 $[ 0,\theta]$ and the estimator

$$M_n = \max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\} $$

What does the above statement mean?

I mean, I can think that the joint distribution is something like

$$\left(\frac1\theta\right)^n $$

But I dont get the max part? The main question in exercise is:

Prove that Mn p→ θ as n → +∞

A proxy question..I am trying to understand example 3.1 here (http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/73125/Publications/%5B3%5D%20Convergence%20of%20Random%20Variables.pdf)

Why is $\ F_n(x) = x^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max of these random variables is less than $x$ if and only if all of them are less than $x$, and since they are independent and identically distributed, the probability of that is the $n$th power of the probability that the first one is less than $x$.